# Keeping a list of methods that have run and running other based on it

Tags: python

What is the most convenient way to do something like this:

```
class AB(object):
    def a1():
        pass # ...
    def a2():
        pass # ...
    def a3():
        pass # ...
    # ...
    def b1():
        pass # ...
    def b2():
        pass # ...
    def b3():
        pass # ...
    # ...
    def B():
        for a_i in a(has been called)
            b_i()
```

It could be done with an internal dictionary but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: "but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way" -- what is the basis of your certainty? You are going to need an internal data-structure and a dictionary is a natural choice.

Comment: Ditto, I think using a dictionary is a pretty straightforward, "elegant" way to do it (or an array, if the functions have indices)

Comment: One reason that dictionaries are natural is that methods themselves can act as keys.